Vertex AI/ML object detection models not running on Coral Devboard any more
I have a big problem that newly traind Vertex AI object detection models are not running on the Dev Board anymore. Older models that were trained (and compiled to EdgeTPU) exactly the same way work fine. I guess someting has changed in the model structure that the board cant handle. All softwrae is updated to the latest version. The error I am getting is:
root@mocha-wasp:/home/mendel/coral/pycoral/examples# python3 detect_image.py -m live_model.tflite -i ../../../data/test.bmp
----INFERENCE TIME----
Note: The first inference is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory.
Aborted
We have hundreds of dev boards running but this bug will make them more or less useless for us.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks
Bernhard
Tried different trainig parameters (precission / performance / balanced)
Tried native tflite export as well as EdgeTPU compiled
Updated all packages on the devboard
